# Blank black screen visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, class, output

I'm not sure why but my console application output is displaying a blank screen with nothing after I debug it and there is no errors on microsoft visual studio.

Below is the code that I am running:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        decimal apple;
        decimal watermelon;
        decimal oranges;
        decimal grapes;
        decimal milk;
        decimal soda;
        decimal subTotal;
        decimal tax,total;
        apple = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
        watermelon = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
        oranges = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
        grapes = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
        milk = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
        soda = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
        subTotal = apple + watermelon + oranges + grapes + milk + soda;
        Console.Write("                          Apple:       ${0}",apple);
        Console.Write("                          watermelon:       ${0}",watermelon);
        Console.Write("                          oranges:       ${0}",oranges);
        Console.Write("                          grapes:       ${0}",grapes);
        Console.Write("                          milk:       ${0}",milk);
        Console.Write("                          soda:       ${0}",soda);
        Console.WriteLine("                          Subtotal:    ${0}", String.Format("{0:0.00}", subTotal));

        tax = subTotal * (0.065M);
        total = tax + subTotal;
        Console.WriteLine("                          Tax:    ${0}", String.Format("{0:0.00}", tax));
        Console.WriteLine("                          Total:    ${0}", String.Format("{0:0.00}", total));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just ran your code and it seems to work fine.
When you run it, you see nothing because you have `Console.ReadLine()` so the console is just blank, waiting for you to enter the `apple` price, then the `watermelon` price, etc... If you precede `apple = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());` with something like `Console.WriteLine("Enter a price for apples:");` then I think you'll at least get some output to console to assure you it is working.

Comment: Also, this code is C# right? `basic` `output` `class` `python` are all incorrect tags. `C#` is appropriate and MAYBE `visual-studio` (but it's really just a regular C# question, from what I can see.

Comment: So when you ran the program were you actual able to get any kind of output on your screen because mine displays just a black screen still

Comment: I ran the program, then I typed numbers with `return`
You're saying that even after you type numbers you get nothing?
At first, it looks like a blank screen, but it is just waiting... I typed a `1` then `return` then `2` then `return` etc until I had filled in all values from `apple` to `soda`. Nothing is on screen during this time, just a blank screen. But it is waiting for input, nonetheless. In your code you have 6 objects from `apple` to `soda` waiting for `ReadLine()` so six times you need to enter a number followed by return until you'll see something happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Console.ReadLine() to hold the screen at the end of you code.

Comment: Console.ReadLine() is already at the beginning of the code. The program is holding, waiting for input; I believe this is why it is "displaying a blank screen with nothing". This code works as-is in my testing.